# Installing SQL Server Express from command line to create Firewall exception

Tags: sql-server

I am using following command line statement to install SQL server.

```
start /wait E:\UnInstall\SQLSERVER\SQLEXPR32And64.EXE /qb username="EZITek" companyname="Ezitek Soft" addlocal=ALL disablenetworkprotocols="2" instancename="CBEServer" SECURITYMODE="SQL" SAPWD="cbeserver123"
```

I want to add something so that setup also creates Firewall exception for SQL server.

Can there be any possibility?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That kind of stuff should be handled by the operating system / firewall. The server application shouldn't ask for exceptions in the firewall. Please, configure your firewall settings separately after you have installed your server.

Answer (score 0):

Firewall exceptions can be added using the `netsh` command, or PowerShell.

- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc776229(v=ws.10).aspx